# ImageView doesn't show full height inside RelativeLayout

Tags: android, imageview, android-relativelayout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/Gray">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImgView"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

the image actual ratio is 360/640, but currently it shows 1:1, the image height doesn't display correctly. I tried to set the image view layout_height to wrap_content but it doesn't work too. How to show the image's height correctly?

[image]

Comment: replace ``android:scaleType="fitXY"`` to ``android:scaleType="centerCrop"``

Comment: How do you want output to look like ? Do you want image ration to be followed? Is it necessary for the image to take up whole width/height of the parent ? Your answer is definitely depends on these 3 parameter `android:scaleType` 
 `android:layout_width` `android:layout_height` play around with those and see what fits your need.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer using Constraint layout as shown below instead of relative layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/Gray"
    android:type="radial"
   >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: @user38931 it will work. Let me know if you are getting any error i can try to fix it

Comment: sorry it works with app:srcCompat, the issue I got is I set the bitmap to ImageView via code. I fixed it. There's nothing wrong with your code

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res  /android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/image"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:scaleType="fitXY"
   android:src="@drawable/snake"
  />
```